# XD Proxy Facebook

Tags: facebook

I am using the facebook connect to login into my website.

In my html page i writen the code:

```
<html>    
<head>    
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />      
<title>Test JOpenID  </title>    
</head>    
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>          
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>          
<script>

     FB.init({
        appId:'180065668680582', 
        cookie:true,
        status: true, 
        xfbml:true
     });

</script>      
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_checkins">
     Login with Facebook
  </fb:login-button>

</body>
</html>
```

So when i click on Login with Facebook button a window pop up and ask to fill the username and password. Till this time everything works properly. Problem persist when i click allow button to enter into the destination web-site. A pop up window appear and disappear also. The till of the window was XD proxy and at the url it is ::

http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php#cb=f183a80ac008141&origin=http%3A%2F%2F174.129.214.219%2Fff715e2f856e19&relation=opener&transport=flash&frame=f1d4f8afdf94ebe&result=%7B%22perms%22%3A%22email%2Cuser_checkins%22%2C%22selected_profiles%22%3A100001492618815%2C%22session%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22session_key%5C%22%3A%5C%222.pRXlnxq8Ig6QwZyJsG732w__.3600.1294326000-100001492618815%5C%22%2C%5C%22uid%5C%22%3A%5C%22100001492618815%5C%22%2C%5C%22expires%5C%22%3A1294326000%2C%5C%22secret%5C%22%3A%5C%225pe7qxMU_7DitJucmcyftA__%5C%22%2C%5C%22access_token%5C%22%3A%5C%22180065668680582%7C2.pRXlnxq8Ig6QwZyJsG732w__.3600.1294326000-100001492618815%7C_QjDI7eTUD32QVvapbsqxn-r4DE%5C%22%2C%5C%22sig%5C%22%3A%5C%22aa66a1d8b234ebe863e386bb8a6520e7%5C%22%7D%22%7D

As per my requirement is concerned i need after allow the facebook is should allow me to enter to the destination site which i already registered. But it only onen a window and disappear in a second.

What is the issue and how to solve tell me in details...

Thanks

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I am getting it with a facebook mobile web site that is having a similar issue (only on one type of phone though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use

```
FB.init({ apiKey: 'API_KEY' });
```

and use

```
FB.init({ appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix it in Opera, just att the following after FB.init():

```
if($.browser.opera ) // it uses jQuery library here!
{
   FB.XD._transport="postmessage";
   FB.XD.PostMessage.init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same issue in IE9, and it seemed to stem from upgrading to Flash Player 10. I'd lost hope in trying to fix it since finding an [open bug at Facebook](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12112) covering it. But [Henson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229424/henson) has posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256756/575530) that fixed it for me. In the JavaScript in my site master I removed the lines

```
    FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function (a, b) { 
    //HACK: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20168
    FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id] = b;
    };
```

and now it works. (N.B. I have not checked to see if the IE8 issue those lines were intended to overcome returns.)